# Python Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python

The scanner works until it finds an external address that is no longer available and then crashes  .

I just want to scan only herold.at and extract the email addresses.

I want him to stop scanning outside addresses. I tried with

`r = requests.get ('http://github.com', allow_redirects = False)` but does not work.

```
import csv
    import requests
    import re
    import time
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Number of pages plus one

allLinks = [];mails=[];
url = 'https://www.herold.at/gelbe-seiten/wien/was_installateur/?page='
for page in range(3):
    time.sleep(5)
    print('---', page, '---')

    
    response = requests.get(url + str(page), timeout=1.001)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
links = [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('a[href]') ]
for i in links:
    #time.sleep(15)
    if(("Kontakt" in i or "Porträt")):
        allLinks.append(i)
allLinks=set(allLinks)

def findMails(soup):
    #time.sleep(15)
    for name in soup.find_all("a", "ellipsis"):
        if(name is not None):
            emailText=name.text
            match=bool(re.match('[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+',emailText))
            if('@' in emailText and match==True):
                emailText=emailText.replace(" ",'').replace('\r','')
                emailText=emailText.replace('\n','').replace('\t','')
                if(len(mails)==0)or(emailText not in mails):
                         print(emailText)
                         mails.append(emailText)

for link in allLinks:
   if(link.startswith("http") or link.startswith("www")):
        r=requests.get(link)
        data=r.text
        soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
        findMails(soup)

   else:
        newurl=url+link
        r=requests.get(newurl)
        data=r.text
        soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
        findMails(soup)

mails=set(mails)
if(len(mails)==0):
    print("NO MAILS FOUND")
```

Error:

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.gebrueder-lamberger.at', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021A24AA7308>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

Comment: Sounds like you'd need to add some code to filter unwanted links out from `allLinks`, right?

Comment: right, i dont need to scann external domain. I need only  herold.at

Comment: Yes. You already have code that recurses through addresses. What's preventing you from adding a filter there?

Comment: Also, your code has no guards against re-scanning URLs that have already been scanned.

Comment: I don't know what to add. You can help me?

Comment: An `if` statement maybe? Maybe try `if 'herold.at' not in newurl:`..?

Comment: and whit re-scanning URLs ?

Comment: That's a different question and will require refactoring your code.

Comment: stil dont work, i don t now wai

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this line `if(link.startswith("http") or link.startswith("www")):` change the `http` into `https` and it should work. I tried it and it fetched all emails.

```
--- 0 ---
--- 1 ---
--- 2 ---
office@smutny-installationen.at
office@offnerwien.at
office@remes-gmbh.at
wien13@lugar.at
office@rossbacher-at.com
office@weiner-gmbh.at
office@wojtek-installateur.at
office@b-gas.at
office@blasl-gmbh.at
gsht@aon.at
office@ertl-installationen.at
office@jakubek.co.at
office@peham-installateur.at
office@installateur-weber.co.at
office@gebrueder-lamberger.at
office@ar-allround-installationen.at
```

Also, you can try the [urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html?highlight=stream#streaming-and-io) to set up your streaming pool.

Comment: not work  requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.installateurexperte.at', port=443)